# how to see open screens from within screen

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

When I open screens from within `screen` with `ctrl-a c`, I can switch back and forth with `ctrl-a n` and `ctrl-a p`. Is there a way that I can see all the open sessions within that single screen instance(for the underlying shell it's just one process)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list all windows within the current session use `windowlist` command: <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, `windowlist`. Alternatively use <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> shortcut. The command accepts options. For example, `-b` switches to the blank window before presenting the list so that the current window is also selectable. Refer to `info screen Windowlist`.

To list the session IDs, use run `screen` with `-ls` option, e.g.:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    4484.another    (Detached)
    4380.pts-1.pavilion (Attached)
2 Sockets in /tmp/screen/S-ruslan.
```

To attach to a detached session, use `-d` option, e.g. `screen -d 4484.another`. To reattach a session, use `-r` option: `screen -d -r SESSION_ID`.